# CSS3 - Put a div alongside a full screen height portrait picture

Tags: image, css, html

I want to display a `div` alongside a portait picture, but I want the `div` to fill all the remaining gap between the picture's right side and the edge of the webpage.

Here is the scheme:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
x| P ||   |x
x| i ||   |x
x| c || D |x
x| t || i |x
x| u || v |x
x| r ||   |x
x| e ||   |x
xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Where `xxx` are the edges of the webpage.

I am not able to get the picture size, because I use the same webpage structure for many other portrait pictures, with not the same ratio, height/width....

What I have been able to do is:

```
<body>

   <img style="float:left; height:100%;" src="portraitpictures_url" >

   <div  style="width: 100%;background:blue;color:white; border-radius:10px;" >

      <p>The div text</p>

   </div>

</body>
```

But this not what I want to have, because my `div` has a 100% width and so my `div` border is hiding partly behind the picture.
If I put my `<img>` tag between `<div>` and `</div>`, my picture's height overflows from the `body` and so is not "screen height".

I am quite sure, it is possible to do better, but here I am stuck...

Here is the full code in Django template style:

```
<body>

   <img  style="float:left; height:calc(100% - 45px);" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ A.picture.name }}" >

   <div  style=" width: 100%; margin-top: 2%;background:red ;color:blue; border-radius:10px;" >

      <p>The div text</p>

   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please avoid using inline style. it's makes your code unreadable and hard to debug. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add width:auto to your second div and set overflow to hidden ,like I've done here : http://jsfiddle.net/h5CU3/ . You can also add horizontal margin to the first block (margin :0 5px 0 0) in case you don't want it to look merged.

```
<body >
 <div  style="float:left; height:100%;">
    <img src="portraitpictures_url" >
 </div>
 <div  style="overflow:hidden;width:auto;overflow:hidden;background:blue;color:white; border-    radius:10px;" >
    <p>The div text</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add float:left to your div as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add style

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I tried to add a overfow:hidden; style to my body tag, but without any effect.

Comment: add img tag overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? (the left margin should be set to the width of the img.

`<body>
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <img style="float:left; height:100%;" src="portraitpictures_url">
        <div style="margin-left:100px;background:blue;color:white; border-radius:10px;">
            <p>The div text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`

Answer (score -2):

Flexbox can do the trick, I have not tried this out yet, but I have read about it. 
I'm sure this is what you are looking for. 
Flexbox is an ongoing project that makes it easy to place 's on the exact spot you want it to be. 
It has a built in function to fill up remaining space automaticaly.

http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html (source: http://learnlayout.com/)